# SQLite isn't returning correct records based on a date

Tags: android, sqlite, date, datetime

I have four buttons on an android app i'm making.
Each button queries an SQLite database and grabs records based on a date. (Buttons are 'Today', 'Week', 'Month', 'All')

The date is stored as a DATETIME in my table, and i'm querying it with a date as well. Everything works well, until i'm grabbing everything that's been done ahead of the previous month.

**Example**

Todays date is June 29th 2016

I create an entry on June 16th 2016 into my SQLite Database and it stores successfully. I create another entry on June 27th 2016 and it stores successfully.

Now I press the 'Today' button and return 0 records. (Correct)

I press the week button and return 1 record (Correct - Created on June 27th)

I press the month button and return 0 records. (Incorrect. I should be getting 2 records)

**The Code**

This is the query I use for my database:

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM job_quote_lookup WHERE created_at >= '" + date + "' ORDER BY created_at ASC"
```

The 'date' is calculated like so:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -31);
Date fromDate = cal.getTime();

date = dateFormat.format(fromDate);
```

(31 represents the largest possible number of days in a month period)

It seems that the problem occurs when the date goes back a month. If I remove 20 days instead of 31, the date will "June 9th" and i will receive BOTH records as i should. But if the date goes into May, i will receive 0 records.

**Other queryStrings i have tried**

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM job_quote_lookup WHERE created_at >= date('now','-31 days') ORDER BY created_at ASC"
```

This didn't seem to work?

I'm still new to Android so apologies if it's a bad question. I have googled around but haven't found anything that might help.

**UPDATE: Extra Info**

Here is some additional code that might be more helpful

The dateFormat used to time stamp entries into my SQLite is:

```
private String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()); //"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" - "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

The date format used when i'm querying my database is:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I'm not sure if this is correct, however my reasoning for leaving "HH:mm" off was due to the "Today" option not working correctly as it would return everything greater than the current time (which is obviously nothing in terms of time stamping)

**Unable to solve...Ended up converting my database DATETIME to INTEGER and storing the date in milliseconds then just converting between date format and milliseconds to query and display information.**

Answer (score 3):

If you want to alter the month of a Java `Calendar` object you will need to use:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

where the above snippet would roll the month back by one.  If you call `cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -31)` on February 15, for example, you get a weird result because the month won't change but the day will roll over.

**Update:**

You *also* have to make sure that the date format you feed into MySQL is correct.  MySQL expects the format `YYYY-MM-DD` for dates, so use this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

I recommend using JodaTime if you expect complex calendar operations.

Comment: I've changed the appropriate code but i'm still returning 0 records. Using the example above for records and the same query string, this is the string output into my Logcat: E/QuotesList: SELECT * FROM job_quote_lookup WHERE created_at >= '29/05/2016' ORDER BY created_at ASC

Comment: Your date format is incorrect for MySQL, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: I've made an edit to my original post to provide some more information that will hopefully be of help :) I tried switching my date format around to match "yyyy-MM-dd" but it returned ALL records regardless of which button was pressed. :(

Comment: The date format I gave is correct.  If you need time resolution then use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` instead.  Are you sure the query should _not_ be returning all records?

Comment: Using the example above again, clicking 'Today' should in theory return 0 results as both of my records were added before the 29th June. However, i changed to your format and it returns all records. Here is the query string using your format: E/QuotesList: SELECT * FROM job_quote_lookup WHERE created_at >= '2016-06-29' ORDER BY created_at ASC